# Gradient slider not working in react-native

Tags: react-native, slider, linear-gradients

I am trying to make a gradient slider for my app in react-native, but I keep getting the message' requireNativeComponent : "BVLinearGradient" was not found in the UIManager' when I run my code.

I tried adding different libraries and other methos that poeple used to fix the same problem. But nothing works.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, 
SafeAreaView, Image, useWindowDimensions, onPress, TextInput, 
Animated} from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation, getStateFromPath } from '@react- 
navigation/native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider'
import { firebase } from '../config'
import Logo from '../assets/temporaryLogoApp.png'
import MultiSlider from '@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider'
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';



const SliderScreen = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);


return(
    <View>

    <Text style={styles.hoi}>
        hoi
    </Text>
    
    <View
      style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: value === 2 ? 'green' : 'grey',
      }}
    />
  </View> */}
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <LinearGradient
    colors={['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']}
    start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
    style={styles.gradient}
  >
    <Slider
      minimumValue={0}
      maximumValue={1}
      value={value}
      onValueChange={setValue}
      style={styles.slider}
      thumbTintColor="#fff"
      minimumTrackTintColor="#transparent"
      maximumTrackTintColor="#transparent"
    />
  </LinearGradient>
  <Text>Value: {value}</Text>
</View>
</View>
)
}

export default SliderScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
gradient: {
height: 40,
width: '100%',
borderRadius: 20,
overflow: 'hidden',
},
slider: {
transform: [
  {
    translateX: -20,
  },
],
},
});
```

Comment: Try to run from android studio.

Comment: Did you run `pod install` after adding the library?